How Can I Create New Sheets To Excel From Anylogic?
I have an Anylogic DES model to which I am performing a Parametersvariation experiment.
I have implemented a counter the counts the total number of experiments run and data collection to excel. During each run, KPI values are collected and after the run written into the excel file.
I would like to implement some code that after each run creates a new sheet in the excel file where this data can be saved. Do you have any idea how to do this?
I have tried using some suggestions I found online, around other java packages but had no success so far and there seems to not be a lot of info available on this specifically to Anylogic.
I hope to be able to save data from individual runs to distinct sheets.

Is google-sheets really involved in this post?

pls only use the "anylogic" tag else you confuse 1000s of other SOF users who have no idea what you are talking about :)

While possible, your data structure is bad. You should not create new sheets for new runs. All runs should simply write into the same sheet  (i.e. simply adding rows at the bottom).
To distinguish the runs, add 2 columns to the only data-output sheet: iteration and replication, both integers.
Then, each "run" (which is a replication of an iteration) can write into the same sheet but fill these columns as well using getCurrentIteration() and getCurrentReplication() (iirc).
Now, you have 1 big fat output sheet with ALL runs and can do proper post-processing as needed.
PS: to create new sheets, write to the xls programmatically using the exportToExternalDB(...) call which allows you to specify a sheet name and will create a new sheet if none found.
